# css - positioning footer: div - ul - div inside div next to each other

Tags: css, html, html-lists, footer

I am trying to position content of my footer. There will be 3 columns inside my footer. On the left, I want "contact informations", in the middle "menu", and on the right "news" 
HTML structure of my footer is like this:

```
 <div id="footercontainer">
   <div id="footer">

     <div id="footerLeft"></div>
     <ul id="footerCenter"> </ul>
     <div id="footerRight"> </div>

   </div>
 </div>
```

My CSS for footer looks like this:

```
 #footer{
 width:1000px;
 margin:auto;
 }
 #footercontainer{
 width:100%;
 height:auto;
 background:url(../img/prechod_stranka-paticka1920x145.png) no-repeat top center;
 background-color:#4e4b47;
 overflow:hidden;
 }

 #footerLeft{
 padding-top:80px;
 padding-bottom:20px;
 width:40%;
 padding-left:30px;
 float:left;
 }

 #footerCenter{width:10%;float:left;padding-top:80px; display:block;}

 #footerRight{padding-top:80px; width:10%; display:block; }
```

Right now footerLeft and footerCenter are next to each other, but footerRight is placed below footerLeft. Can anyone help me, how to put them next to each other please?

Answer (score 0):

this is a basic markup for 3 col layout

http://jsfiddle.net/cancerian73/8Lqr6/

```
*, *:before, *:after {
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.common-div {
width:33.33%;
min-height:200px;
float:left;
}
.left {
background-color:#CCC
}
.right {
background-color:#930
}
.center {
background-color:#9C6
}
```

is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `display:block` to `display:inline-block` for footerRight div.

```
#footerRight{ padding-top:80px; width:10%; display:inline-block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/3SDCT/

Add a `float:left` to your `#footerRight` if you want your right footer nudged up to the center or you can `float:right` if you want it to be nudged to the right edge of your `#footerContainer`.

I put a red border just so you could see your div's.  Also I wrapped you unordered list in a div.

Hope this helps